# District building limitations in Civ 6

Tags: civilization-6

During play I have noticed sometimes I can't build certain districts on certain types of land.

For example, a campus can't be built on a resource (irritating if a resource is next to lots of mountains)

Is there an exhaustive list of all these limitations anywhere - what can and can't be built where?

Comment: I'm not sure what limitations you are referring to because other than limitations of population size, and encampments not being allowed adjacent to the city center, there are none. If you place a district on top of a resource, it will remove that resource (it prompts you and notifies you of this) - since districts do not provide any workable tile or value.

Comment: Also worth noting that Wonders do have restrictions on the locations they can be built (terrain, adjacent districts etc).

Comment: @n_palum That's not true - several zones can't be built on hills - or on top of resources, for example. And yes adding wonders to this would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/District_(Civ6)), the limitations are as follows

- Floodplains (unless you're Egypt).
- Strategic/Luxury Resources (Unless it was built before that strategic resource was revealed, in which case you're granted access once it is researched).
- Antiquity Sites or Shipwrecks before you've excavated them.
- Already existing Wonders/Districts
- Non-Clearable Features (e.g. If you don't have mining you can't build a district on a forest).
- Harbor Districts must be adjacent to land.
- Aerodome and Spaceport districts must be on flat land (no hills).
- Aqueducts must be one tile away from both your city center and a mountain, river, or lake tile.

It states that you can place districts on bonus resources but they will be removed.